# Relation between net.inet.tcp.recvspace, SO_RCVBUF, Direct ByteBuf and ByteBufAllocator in Netty

Tags: tcp, netty, nio

Can someone quickly explain how Netty/NIO consumes TCP buffers from OS?

I reckon the TCP sliding window ACKs are managed by OS TCP stack (recvspace) and are sent back after each packet (MTU size) till the recvspace is full.

Then after NIO selector triggers a receive event, NIO (in direct buf mode) creates a direct buffer pointing to the same memory area and marks it as read? Or does it copy from recvspace into another buffer?

If this is the case, then what's each application's SO_RCVBUF? Is it relevant at all?

My goal is to read from then next buffer (and hence send new ACKs to read more) only after fully consuming the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> I reckon the TCP sliding window ACKs are managed by OS TCP stack (recvspace) and are sent back after each packet (MTU size) till the recvspace is full.

Correct. This happens from the socket receive buffer, which is in the kernel.

> Then after NIO selector triggers a receive event, NIO (in direct buf mode) creates a direct buffer

Not necessarily. I don't see a reason for it to be a direct buffer.

> pointing to the same memory area

No. It is in the application space.

> and marks it as read?

No.

> Or does it copy from recvspace into another buffer?

Correct. It reads, by calling ReadableByteChannel.read(), which ultimately calls recv(), which copies data out of the socket receive buffer into application memory.

> If this is the case, then what's each application's SO_RCVBUF? Is it relevant at all?

It's the first thing mentioned above.